# through associations in sails.js

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

A while ago I asked how to perform the "Through Associations". 
I have the following tables :

```
genres
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | 
| slug      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
| parent_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
genres_radios
+----------+--------+------+-----+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key |
+----------+--------+------+-----+
| genre_id | int(6) | NO   | MUL |
| radio_id | int(6) | NO   | MUL |
+----------+--------+------+-----+
radios
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(5)       | NO   | PRI | 
| slug      | varchar(100) | NO   |     |
| url       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
```

The answer is there : [Sails.js associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417104/sails-js-associations).

Now I was wondering, if I had a new field in the genres_radios table, for example:

```
genres_radios
+----------+--------+------+-----+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key |
+----------+--------+------+-----+
| genre_id | int(6) | NO   | MUL |
| new_field| int(10)| NO   |     |
| radio_id | int(6) | NO   | MUL |
+----------+--------+------+-----+
```

How would I do to get that attribute while making the join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not implemented yet. Quoting [Waterline's documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md) :

> Many-to-Many Through Associations
>
> Many-to-Many through associations behave the same way as many-to-many
>   associations with the exception of the join table being automatically
>   created for you. This allows you to attach additional attributes onto
>   the relationship inside of the join table.
>
> Coming Soon