# Sails / WaterLine ORM / Has Many Through: Insert data into join table

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I'm newbie with Sails/WaterLine ORM 
I'm following http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations

One question. 
How way to insert data into a join table ? 
For example: **User m - m Pet**

User model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  pets:{
    collection: 'pet',
    via: 'owner',
    through: 'petuser'
  }
}
```

Pet model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  color: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  owners:{
    collection: 'user',
    via: 'pet',
    through: 'petuser'
  }
}
```

PetUser model (join table)

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner:{
      model:'user'
    },
    pet: {
      model: 'pet'
    }
  }
}
```

Pet data is available (some record with ID1, ID2, ID3...) 
I want to add new one user with some pets 
PetUser ( id , id_of_user, id_of_pet) 
1, U1, P1 
2, U1, P2

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "pets" : [2,3]
}
```

**UserController**

```
module.exports = {

    addUserWithPets: function(req, res) {
    User.create(req.body).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else { 
            /*pets.forEach(function(pet, index){
                user.pets.add(pet);
            })
            user.save(function(err) {});*/

            user.pets.add(data);

            user.save(function(err) {});
        }

        return res.ok({
            data: user
        });

    })
  } 
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this hasn't been implemented yet in sails.

Refer to this question: [through associations in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562147/through-associations-in-sails-js) on SO.

Here is what [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations/many-to-many-through.md) say:

> Many-to-Many through associations behave the same way as many-to-many associations with the exception of the join table being automatically created for you. This allows you to attach additional attributes onto the relationship inside of the join table.
>
> **Coming Soon**